# How to optimize battery consumption during continuous audio record in background in Android?

Tags: android, performance, audio-recording

Need to continuously do audio record and process the signal in background in a service. It is working fine, but it consumes battery a lot. How to optimize this?

Comment: have you been able to do this yet?